# Spectrum Smoothing

Tags: fft, gnuradio, smoothing

I recently stumbled upon this GNU Radio flow graph which smooths spectrum. Block parameters are seen in image attached below. Also visually results doesn't change if I take out "Keep 1 in N" block. I know visually this can be achieved by averaging regular frequency sink block but I wanna know how and why is this approach working too. Is there any name for this DSP method?
[image: flow-graph]
[image: fft]

Comment: what do you mean with "how and why it works"? I mean, the how it works is literally given by the flow graph. "Why it works": I contest it *works*: "Working" is something you can do *for a purpose*. Which is? "displaying a smooth spectrum" is not very useful in itself – unless you can show that this smoothed spectrum contains the info **you** need (which we don't know!). What is the information you mean to extract from the spectrum?

Comment: and very frankly, "keep 1 in N" with N=1 is quite obviously a no-operation.

Comment: and "I recently stumbled upon" clearly indicates you should maybe link to your source to help us understand your context :)